# How to make a IEEE cross-reference?

Tags: ieeetran

The IEEE cross-reference notation is `[1, Fig. 2]` that means “in Fig. 2 of reference [1]”,  how to make this one in my latex.

My code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{ugrinovskii13,
doi = {10.1109/tac.2013.2256675},
author={Valery Ugrinovskii},
volume = {58},
number = {10},
pages = {2659-2664},
title = {Conditions for Detectability in Distributed Consensus-Based Observer       Networks},
journal ={IEEE trans. Automat. Contr.}
 }
\end{filecontents*}

    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
Fig. 2 of  \cite{ugrinovskii13}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of loading the `cite` package, you could load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers` and issue the command `\cite[Fig.~2]{<key>}`.

Comment: tried, error happened, `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.`

Comment: Did you load `natbib` with the option `numbers`?

Comment: Isn't it you suggested, `\cite[Fig.~2]{<key>}`?

Comment: It works, thanks, I know what you mean, `\usepacke[number]{natbib}`

Comment: @Mico but there're two side effects:1) the layout of the reference is bigger than before; 2)different style, for example: before, [3],[26]; now, [3, 26]. How to solve these problem?

Comment: @Mico I solved the problem, no need to do `\usepacke[number]{natbib}`, just `\usepackage{cite}`, then, `\cite[Fig.~2]{<key>}`, everything is fine now? thanks.

Comment: You can put it in the text `Fig.~2 of [1]`. If you send it for publication, they will do it for you. If you are not going to publish it you can write whatever you want. Either way, no need for such thing since `Fig.~2` is a static text.

Comment: Instead of adding "solved" in the title, you can make your own answer and accept it to mark the question as solved....

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @Mico, I solved this problem, just `\usepackage{cite}`, then, `\cite[Fig.~2]{ugrinovskii13}`, everything is fine now.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{ugrinovskii13,
doi = {10.1109/tac.2013.2256675},
author={Valery Ugrinovskii},
volume = {58},
number = {10},
pages = {2659-2664},
title = {Conditions for Detectability in Distributed Consensus-Based Observer          Networks},
journal ={IEEE trans. Automat. Contr.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\cite[Fig.~2]{ugrinovskii13}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]